# How can we mark a question as solved when your problem is solved by a comment?

Tags: discussion, questions

1 year and 9 months ago, I asked a question on Stack Overflow. I received a few comments on my question and I understood what the problem was. There are no answers on my question page, but I had gotten my answer in less than an hour.

Today, I was exploring my profile and I came across this question. Now I am wondering if there is a way to indicate that the problem has been solved. Here are a few options that crossed my mind:

**1. Answer the question myself (with the help of
comment that actually answered my question) and mark it as accepted**

It is the easiest way I can think of, but it does not seem ethical to me. Writing someone else's answer as my own answer does not feel right.

**2. Close the question**

There are some forums where you close question when it is solved, but on Stack Overflow, only bad and duplicate questions are closed. So, that's not an option either.

**3. Delete the question**

The question I am talking about is not very important or common, so, at a point, I thought of deleting it, but that question is not complete garbage either. It is a kind of question that beginners often face. Also, speaking in general, deleting the question cannot be a solution to this problem.

**4. Request the person who answered the question in the comment section to write an answer**

Right now, it looks like the best way to solve this issue to me. But, I was wondering if there is any other way. so, I will go for this option if I don't get any other way to solve the issue.

> My question: Is there another way?

In case you were wondering about the question I am talking about, you can check it here: *[AttributeError: module 'docx' has no attribute 'Document' while trying to execute .py file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54642586/attributeerror-module-docx-has-no-attribute-document-while-trying-to-execut)*

P.S.: My issue here is not completely about the question I mentioned. I am talking about questions in general, because I have seen people answering questions and solving issues in comments.